# group by multiple and sum laravel collection

Tags: laravel, array, group-by, sum, collection

estoy trabajando con un array utilizando laravel collect donde necesito sumar los "totales_validos", agrupandolos por parametro y centro. Ejemplo:

```
Este es mi array:

{[
  "centro" => 5,
  "parametro" => "manzana",
  "totales_validos" => 12
],
[
  "centro" => 5,
  "parametro" => "manzana",
  "totales_validos" => 12
],
[
  "centro" => 5,
  "parametro" => "pera",
  "totales_validos" => 2
],
[
  "centro" => 1,
  "parametro" => "manzana",
  "totales_validos" => 12
],
[
  "centro" => 1,
  "parametro" => "manzana",
  "totales_validos" => 12
]}

Esto debería arrojarme lo siguiente:

{[
 "centro" => 5,
 "parametro" => "manzana",
 "suma_totales_validos" => 24
 ],
 [
 "centro" => 5,
 "parametro" => "pera",
 "suma_totales_validos" => 2
 ],
 [
 "centro" => 1,
 "parametro" => "manzana",
 "totales_validos" => 24
 ]}
```

Lo más cerca que he estado es agrupando solo por centro, pero claramente no diferencia parametros y no aparece la información correcta.

```
$groupwithcount = $grouped->groupBy('centro')->map(function ($group) {

   return [
    'centro' =>  $group->first()['centro'],
    'parametro' =>  $group->first()['parametro'],
    'totales_validos' => $group->sum('totales_validos')

 ];
});

Devolviendome lo siguiente:

{[
 "centro" => 5,
 "parametro" => "manzana",
 "suma_totales_validos" => 26
 ],
 [
 "centro" => 1,
 "parametro" => "manzana",
 "totales_validos" => 24
]}
```

Como se puede notar, suma solo por centros y omite el valor 2 del parámetro "pera" sumándolo incorrectamente al anterior. No tengo muy claro cómo hacer dos GroupBy y a la vez sumar, agradecería mucha su ayuda, pues llevo muchos intentos fallidos!

Answer (score 1):

Obtienes ese resultado porque sólo agrupas por `centro`, aún te falta agrupar por `parametro`. Aquí te dejo una idea sobre cómo podrías hacerlo, puedes modificarlo a tus necesidades.

```
$finalGrouped = collect([]);

$collection
    ->groupBy('centro')
    ->each(function($center, $centerKey) use ($finalGrouped) {
        $center
            ->groupBy('parametro')
            ->each(function($param, $paramKey) use ($centerKey, $finalGrouped) {
                $finalGrouped->push([
                    'centro' => $centerKey,
                    'parametro' => $paramKey,
                    'totales_validos' => $param->sum('totales_validos')
                ]);
            });
        });

dd($finalGrouped);
```